# UIPageViewController value pass null on next page

Tags: ios, iphone, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

When I try to send string value one page to next page in `UIPageViewController`, I get a  `null` result, is there any other way to pass the value one to next view?

Here's the relevant part of my code:

In the first page:

```
(void)cheakvalication{
    PageContentViewController *pgvc = [[PageContentViewController alloc]init];
    pgvc.strname=txtfirstname.text;
    NSLog(@"txt:%@ , str : %@",pgvc.strname,txtfirstname.text);
}
```

In the second:

```
(IBAction)OnClickRegister:(id)sender {
    PageContentViewController1 *pgvc1 = [[PageContentViewController1 alloc]init];
    [pgvc1 cheakvalication];
    NSLog(@"name : %@",[self.strname description]);
}
```

All NSLog calls output `null`.

Comment: you said that all NSLog calls output null. it means your txtfirstname.text also call null output..?

Comment: yes , txtfristname.text is null because in pageviewcontroller control gone in next page so frist page textfield data shows null , it's any other way to get data from frist page to second page in pageviewcontroller?